# Keep content inside child div

Tags: html, css

I have a div set to position:relative as my parent div

the child div's inside are all set to position:absolute so that they stay inside of the parent div
(i did this in an effort to have some "responsive-ness" for different display sizes)

however, now that i have used this method for the primary elements of the site, i cant seem to add tables to the child div that i want to use as a content area. im sure this is because tables act like divs and their position will be relative to the parent div

so im assuming there is no way to keep content inside of a child div?? no clearfix or anything?? :O)

Comment: Can you provide your `html` and your `css`, please?

Comment: there is one parent div and 3 child div's inside. 

the parent is set to relative and the children are set to absolute. 

if i add a table inside one of the child divs, it positions itself based on the parent div, not the child div which it is inside of. 

is there anyway to make content such as tables and/or div's stay inside a child div??